# ar_pose on ROS Hydro

Tags: ar-pose, ros-fuerte, ros-hydro, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I've been using *ar_pose* on ROS Fuerte for some time, but I want to update and start working with ROS Hydro. However, *ar_pose* doesn't work when using Groovy and Hydro.

Is there any update or any changes that should be made in order to have it working?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101281/ar_pose-on-ros-hydro/) by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-11-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-11-14**:
This might be obvious, but make sure you're using the proper repo (https://github.com/IHeartEngineering/ar_tools). It's been moved around a bit lately.

**Comment by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on 2014-01-20**:
Thank you for your comment! Well, I'm using this repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There were some [compilation errors](http://answers.ros.org/question/79841/can-someone-help-me-installing-artoolkit-on-ubuntu-1204-and-ros-hydro/), after solving them, it works fine.
It's a rosbuild package, so you have to [create a rosbuild workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin#rosbuild_workspace_on_top_of_catkin_workspace) then download ar_pose and build it.

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on 2014-01-20**:
Hi Artem. Thank you for this sugestion! It still doesn't work. Here is what I do:

$roscore;
$rosrun camera1394 camera1394_node _video_mode:=640x480_rgb8 /camera/image_raw:=usb_cam/image_raw;
$ROS_NAMESPACE=usb_cam rosrun image_proc image_proc;
$rosrun ar_pose ar_multi;
$rosrun rviz rviz

**Comment by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on 2014-01-20**:
Also, I add "Camera", "Grid" and "Marker" on ''rviz'' and I set Fixed Frame to "/camera", Marker Topic to "visualization_marker", and Image Topic to "/usb_cam/image_raw".

Any suggestion?